# Why can a Barker-7 code be represented by the array [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 3] too?

Tags: python, signal-processing, simulation

I need to implement a Barker-7 and Barker-13 code for my project and my professor gave me part of a source code.

I understand how the code works and translated it successfully from MATLAB to Python but I don't understand why the "normal" Barker-7 code [ 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 1, -1] can be represented using [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 3].

Also, how can I implement a Barker-13 code in the same style instead of using [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1]?

```
# Sampling frequency
f_s = 48000

# Duration of one chip (sequence element)
tc = 0.4

# Time vector
t = np.arange(0, tc, 1/f_s)

# Carrier frequency
f0 = 2000

# Barker 7 code: 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 1, -1
# Phase shift values for each element
order = np.pi  # PSK pi QPSK pi/2
jump_seq = order * np.array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 3])

# Duration of one chip in the signal
chip_dur = len(t) / len(jump_seq)

# Phase vector initialization
phi = np.zeros_like(t)

# Assigning phase shifts to the signal
for j in range(len(jump_seq)):
   # Calculate the indices corresponding to the current chip duration
   start_idx = int((j - 1) * chip_dur) + 1
   end_idx = min(int(j * chip_dur), len(t))
   
   # Assign the phase shift values to the corresponding indices
   phi[start_idx:end_idx] = jump_seq[j]

# Generate the modulated signal
x = np.exp(1j * phi) * np.exp(1j * 2 * np.pi * f0 * t)
```

I tried the code with [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1]

Comment: The numbers in [0,0,0,1,1,2,3] increment every time the sign flips in [1,1,1,-1,-1,1,-1].  Thus, it's always possible to construct one from the other.